# Automapper: sequence contains no elements.

Tags: c#, automapper

When using Automapper with a generic repository like so:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets all DTOs 
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
/// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException"></exception>
public virtual IEnumerable<TDto> GetAll()
{
        return Mapper.Map<List<TDto>>(_repository.ReadAll());
}
```

Automapper throws an exception "sequence contains no elements" if the repository does not return any records.

It's entirely possible that records may not exist at the time when the method is called.

Is there a way I can get Automapper to return an empty IEnumerable in the event that no records are present instead of throwing this ugly exception?

Comment: Please show us the `ReadAll` method. And please include a screenshot of the exception when it occurs so we can see the stack trace.

Comment: Most likely the issue is your code, not AM. Try to make a repro.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu you were right. I added an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to be that I had a mapping which tried to get the last element from a sequence. Instead it should have used LastOrDefault:

I changed:

`ForMember(dest => dest.PlacedObjectDimension, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PlacedObjectDimensions.ToList().Last()));`

to:

`.ForMember(dest => dest.PlacedObjectDimension, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PlacedObjectDimensions.ToList().LastOrDefault()));`

As this was happening inside a map defnition it the error was a little "trickier" to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a variable which reads from repository, check if repository returned any data, if it's not null then map data and return it, otherwise return empty IEnumerable ?